# How to recursively build an answers object in React?

Tags: reactjs, recursion

I built a QuestionsTree component that displays a question, and then according to the answer displays another question and so on.
The component works correctly in displaying the questions, but I'd like to recursively build the answers object as well.

The component code is :

```
import React from 'react';
import {useState} from 'react';
import Question from "./Question";


const QuestionTree = (props) => {
    const {questionnaire, answersCb} = props;
    const [moreQuestions, setMoreQuestions] = useState(null);
    const handleAnswer = (answer)=>{
        console.log('answer: ', answer);
        answersCb(answer);
        const option = questionnaire.options.find(option=> option.value === answer[questionnaire.id]);
        if (option && option.question) {
            setMoreQuestions(
                <QuestionTree
                    questionnaire={option.question}
                    answersCb={answersCb}
            />);
        };
    };


    return (
        <div>
            <Question
                answerReceived={handleAnswer}
                question={questionnaire.question}
                questionId={questionnaire.id}
                options={questionnaire.options}
            />
            {moreQuestions}
        </div>
    );
};

export default QuestionTree;
```

Here is a link to my repo with the entire project :
https://bitbucket.org/rugggger/react-components/src/master/src/components/

Currently the answersCb returns only the clicked on answer -

```
{ 
 "question-1": 1
 }
```

How do I write the 'answersCb' function to return me the current state of all the answers the users chose ? 
Something like:

```
{
"question-1": 1,
"question-3": 4,
"question-5": 3
}
```

Comment: You could do a `useEffect` in `Questionnaire` component to keep track of all given answers. Something like in the following [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/1nfdn).

Comment: @AWolf It's not quite what I am looking for. I want the answer object to reflect the current state of the toggled buttons. And I want all the code to belong in the QuestionsTree component.

Comment: @Yaron OK, you could create a container component that's storing the answers like in the following [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cuuoe). You need a component that is not recusively called so you can store the answers. Just selecting a question that will change the available questions is a problem as that's not reflected in the answers object.

Comment: @AWolf I updated the repository so that the component passes an 'answers' object down and receives an onChange callback that updates the 'answers' object.  Do you understand why the answers object doesn't get updated ? according to console.log it updates correctly but the component doesn't render the changes.

Comment: If you create a new object like `const newAnswers = Object.assign({}, answers, answer);` and call `onChange(newAnswers)` in `handleAnswerClicked` it should work. I think it mutated answers before.